# Verify google play subscription with IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, ionic3

I'm implementing https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase with ionic to get info about google play subscriptions in my app, but i can't get the status of subscriptions... I need to know if user cancelled and the date of expiration. Anyone know how can I do this?﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a bit late to answer, but maybe I will help someone else.

In my opinion, the best way to achieve this is **to store the subscription information in your server database** (so use server side receipt validation). **Two good articles** that demonstrate how to achieve this (With the PHP Laravel Framework), and explain the validation flow ([iOS](http://blog.goforyt.com/validating-ios-app-purchases-laravel/) and [Android](http://blog.goforyt.com/validating-android-app-purchases-laravel/))

Basically, you just need **to send the data receipt to your backend and store the receipt field** where you will find all information (Purchase time, expiration Date, User cancel reason ...). Useful links for [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html) and [Android](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions).